# Generate responsive post thumbnails of same size

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, images, responsive

I am using a function to display related posts in my wordpress theme with their thumbnail. I am using [uikit](http://getuikit.com/) to make my theme responsive. Uikit offers a grid feature similar to the bootstrap one, and it also automatically resizes the images according to the available space.
What I want to do is to get thumbnails of the same width and height even if the thumbnail needs to be stretched/cropped.
Is it possible to edit it so that I get images of same size for each thumbnail? At the moment I'm getting this result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgI60.png

I am using the following code and I've already tried the solution suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87208/thumbnail-with-different-sizes):

```
<?php
function getthe_related_posts(){
    $html='<h3>Related posts:</h3><div class="uk-grid uk-container-center" >';   
    $orig_post = $post;  
    global $post;  
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);  

    if ($tags) {  
        $tag_ids = array();  
        foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;  
        $args=array(  
            'tag__in' => $tag_ids,  
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),  
            'posts_per_page'=>4, // Number of related posts to display.  
            'caller_get_posts'=>1  
        );  

        $my_query = new wp_query( $args );  
        $width=$args['posts_per_page'];
        $count = 0;
        while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {  
            $my_query->the_post();    

            $html.='<div class="uk-panel uk-panel-space uk-width-medium-1-4 uk-width-small-1-1 uk-text-center"><a class="" href="'.get_the_permalink($post->ID).'">';  
            $html.=get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID); 
            $html.='<br/><span>'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</span>';
            $html.='</a>';
            $html.='</div>'; 
            $count = $count+1;
        }  
    }  
    $post = $orig_post;  
    wp_reset_query();  
    $html.='</div>';
    return str_replace('uk-width-medium-1-4','uk-width-medium-1-'.$count,$html);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/

and regenerate all thumbnails.

Or steps:

1. Create new dimension for images:
   `add_image_size ('thumb-cropped', 227, 133, true); // Set necessary sizes (true = cropped)`
2. Get images with the sizes in you function.

   `get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);`

   fix to:

   `get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumb-cropped');`
3. Install plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/
4. Inter in admin area and regenerate all thumbnails
5. The end. Use all new images with fixed dimension